# How to plot the normal distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

According to 'An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications', Vol. 1 by Feller the number of inversions in a random permutations at large numbers satisfy CLT with dedicated mean and variance.

However, I am practically intrested in how to plot the figure of the normal distribution (what to calculate for it)?

I understand that the figure may depends on the fact of how large the numbers are. Any explanations to clarify the topic are highly welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to plot the PDF $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$ or the CDF $\frac{1}{2}\left[1+\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right]$? Either way, the case $\mu=0,,\sigma=1$ is worth using for definiteness.

Comment: The PDF one, which depends on the number of elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to plot the density function of $N(0,1)$:
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} .
$$

In *Mathematica*, a one-liner:

```
Plot[PDF[NormalDistribution[], x], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image]

In *Python*, slightly more verbose:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-4, 4, 101)
y = np.exp(-x*x/2) / np.sqrt(2*np.pi)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Federico! How can I get the N(0,1) if there are mean and variance which depend on the number of elements?

Comment: Translate and rescale: if $Z\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$, then $(Z-\mu)/\sigma\sim N(0,1)$.

Comment: Could you add the figures here for mean=n(n-1)/4, variance=(2n^3+3n^2-5n)/72 at n=10, 100, 1000?

Comment: They don't look any different from the one I plotted. They are just translated and stretched. Only the numbers on the axes change